# How to insert variable results into calls in Django Template Language

Tags: python, django

In Django I'm trying to make a generic "confirm action" call which I can easily pass the final address to, but I'm having difficulty inserting a variable in the link:

```
<a href="{% url 'view_do_confirm_action' 'url view_delete_object object.object_name' %}"> Delete this object </a><br>
```

In case it's not clear, the argument to view_do_confirm_action is the url to be followed if the user confirms.  The final url I would like to be followed links to this pattern:

```
path('objects/object/<str:object_name>/delete', views.view_delete_object, name='view_delete_object'),
```

"url view_delete_object object.object_name" is not being resolved at the right time here - any advice?

Thank you

scan

Comment: I don't understand what the generated URL should look like. Can you show the relevant urlpattern?

Comment: Change `{{ object.object_name }}` this to `object.object_name` and try.

Comment: I did that change and it was better, but it made me realise the bigger problem is the "url" resolution.  I've edited the question to reflect it (and to show relevant urlpattern)

Comment: `view_do_confirm_action` pattern is more interesting. Btw, why do you need/want to hit backend once again for a confirmation?

Comment: you can't use {% url %} inside of {% url %}. You can create a variable `{% url view_delete_object object.object_name  as delete_url %}` and then use `delete_url` in your second `{% url %}`

Comment: But you haven't shown the pattern for `view_do_confirm_action`, which is what we need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**urls.py**

```
path('<str:object_name>/delete', ViewBarDrinkDetail, name='view_delete_object'),
path('confirm/<str:url_text>', ViewBarDrinkUpdate, name='view_do_confirm_action'),
```

Your top url `view_do_confirm_action` is taking a *url_text*, this url_text will obviously contain **/**, with these dynamic slashes Django won't be able to resolve your `view_do_confirm_action`.

**Solutions**

Try changing your pattern:

```
path('/confirm/<str:object_name>/delete', ViewBarDrinkDetail, name='view_do_confirm_action'),
```

**Use Custom Template Tag**

```
@register.simple_tag
def pass_url_to_reverse_name(name, arg_url_name, arg_url_args):

    arg_resolved_url = reverse(arg_url_name, args=[arg_url_args])
    resolved_url = reverse(name, args=[arg_resolved_url])

    return resolved_ur
```

In template Use it like this:

```
<a href="{% pass_url_to_reverse_name 'view_do_confirm_action' 'view_delete_object' request.user.id %}"> Delete this object </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put another expression in django template expression.

You're passing a url as parameter to another url.

Instead of

```
<a href="{% url 'view_do_confirm_action' 'url view_delete_object {{ object.object_name }}' %}"> Delete this object </a><br>
```

Do

```
{% url view_delete_object object.object_name as the_url %}
<a href="{% url 'view_do_confirm_action' the_url %}"> Delete this object </a><br>
```

Comment: correct but without the {{ }} around `object.object_name`

Comment: @dirkgroten thanks. I did the same mistake as questioner lol. Looks OK now?

Comment: It's very close but I'm getting a reverse error because (I think) the_url has a slashes in it.  I've tried putting '' around url view_delete_object object.object_name but that didn't resolve... and putting '' around the_url in the href just forwards the string 'the_url'

Comment: @Omroth can you post your django url path. Let me see how it looks.

Comment: path('objects/object/<str:object_name>/delete', views_objects.view_delete_object, name='view_delete_object'),

Comment: @Omroth and your `view_do_confirm_action` path ?

Comment: @Omroth please post the other path too. maybe it's better to accomplish this using custom template tags.

Comment: Sorry guys, thanks so much for the help:
path('confirm/<str:url_text>', views.view_do_confirm_action, name='view_do_confirm_action'),

Comment: @Omroth you are right, the problem is the **/** in url's. The `/confirm/<url_text>/delete` will not resolve properly.

Comment: I'd rather send the {% url 'views_whatever' arg %} but I can't get that to resolve.

Comment: @Omroth check another answer, should give you some more help. The current answer may help someone in future so I'm not keeping it as it is and that's why I posted another one.